# Change CloudFront response using lambda@Edge

Tags: request, geolocation, response, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have been trying to use lambda@edge to add the CloudFront-viewer-country header to my response, I managed to trigger the function and its working, but I can't see any logs in cloudWatch, cloudWatch is only logging the test which is done on the function page not the real test that got trigged by visiting the website, I googled how to find the logs and found out that its in cloudWatch of the nearest region that received the request, but I could not find any.

I have tried two methods to change my response one of them was on stack overflow answers: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633610/how-do-i-get-cloudfront-viewer-country-to-appear-in-response-headers`

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
   const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
   if(request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'])
   {
      response.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'] = request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'];
   }
   return callback(null,response);
};
```

This method when gets tested from the lambda page it works, but when I test by accessing the website I get 503 server error: The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions.

So can someone help in these permissions, please note that I have the following policy on my s3 bucket which static hosts my website:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::outfityard-app-client/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The other method that I have tried was using the following function in my lambda:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    const uri = request.uri === "/index.html" ? "/" : request.uri;
    var countryCode = null;
    if(headers["cloudfront-viewer-country"]) {
        countryCode = headers["cloudfront-viewer-country"][0].value;
    }
    console.log(`Country detected: '${countryCode}'`);

    if (countryCode !== "US") {
        const response = {
            status: "200",
            statusDescription: "Found",
            headers: {
                ["cache-control"]: [
                    {
                        key: "Cache-Control",
                        value: "no-cache, no-store, private"
                    }
                ],
                ["cloudfront-viewer-country"]: [
                    {
                        key: "cloudfront-viewer-country",
                        value: countryCode
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
        callback(null, response);
    } else {
        callback(null, request);
    } 
};
```

This method is returning the expected response but nothing gets loaded from my website which I don't understand why! here is the response headers that I received:

```
Content-Type →text/html
Content-Length →1217
Connection →keep-alive
Server →CloudFront
Date →Fri, 16 Aug 2019 11:37:19 GMT
X-Cache →LambdaExecutionError from cloudfront
Via →1.1 9891f2220bf61a27cb1f26085ab3703d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop →CDG3-C2
X-Amz-Cf-Id →D542SzvAsMYAXIOcBUwHWEB5_lAf41t1wWULh6LcXwagAvjFRvH5nA==
```

I have used the following and its working fine but I don't know if its the right way to do it:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
   const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
   const value = request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'][0].value;
   const key = request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'][0].key;
   response.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'] = [{key: key, value: value}];
   return callback(null,response);
};
```

Comment: - Is your S3 static-site able to load if you don't use the Lambda?

"managed to trigger the function and its working, but I can't see any logs in cloudWatch"...How do you know you triggered the function if there aren't any logs in CloudWatch?

Comment: What region are you deploying this Lambda in? It looks like Lambda@Edge only works in the US East (N. Virginia) Region: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works.html

Comment: @YannStoneman Yes its working fine without lambda@edge, I managed to figure it out because I can see the new response or redirection in my response.

Comment: @YannStoneman My lambda is in the N.Virginia region

Comment: I'm curious why you're doing this: `const uri = request.uri === "/index.html" ? "/" : request.uri;`. Why are you removing `index.html` from requests?

Comment: Have you tried the debugging steps here, like checking if the service-linked roled exists in your account, etc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-testing-debugging.html#lambda-edge-testing-debugging-cloudwatch-logs-enabled

Comment: @YannStoneman I have added an answer which is working fine for me but not sure if its the right way to do it.