# AWS Lambda 'Origin Request' send CF Country 'header' to browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on an 'Origin Request' for AWS Cloudfront to;

- Get the value of `cloudfront-viewer-country`
- For instance 'NZ' or 'AU'
- If it has a value, send that value to browser response so we can use it.

Here's what I have, it feels close but I'm getting errors on line

```
'use strict';

  // Origin Request
  exports.handler = (evt, ctx, cb) => {
    var request = evt.Records[0].cf.request;
    var response = evt.Records[0].cf;

    const headers = request.headers;

    if(headers['cloudfront-viewer-country']) {
      response['headers']['cloudfront-viewer-country'] = (headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'] || [ { value: 'XX' } ]);
    }
    return cb(null, response);
  };
```

Current Error:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Simply the below ... Not 'Origin Request' but 'Origin Response' worked for me. Based on: [Change CloudFront response using lambda@Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524006/change-cloudfront-response-using-lambdaedge)

```
// Origin Response

exports.handler = (evt, ctx, cb) => {
  const request = evt.Records[0].cf.request;
  const response = evt.Records[0].cf.response;

  const value = request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'][0].value;
  const key = request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'][0].key;

  response.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'] = [{key: key, value: value}];

  return cb(null, response);
};
```