# How do I get CloudFront-Viewer-Country to appear in browser request headers?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront for S3 that my application is calling to get the assets. I have a origin request policy that has "Headers - Include the following headers > **CloudFront-Viewer-Country** and **CloudFront-Viewer-City**" . Despite this, when I check the request headers in the browser console, i don't see any of those two when I can see the "Hit from cloudfront" in the response headers. I'm able to modify response headers and it shows the change in the browser but any headers wherther it be Cloutfront-viewer-* or any custom header that I add are not showing.

I've also tried adding cloudfront function to behaviors > function associations > viewer request

```
function handler(event) {
    const request = event.request;
    const clientIP = event.viewer.ip;
    
    //Add the true-client-ip header to the incoming request
    request.headers['viewer-ip'] = {value: clientIP};
    
    return request;
}
```

as well as adding this lambda@edge function to the behaviors > function associations > origin request

```
'use strict';

export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   const request = event.Records[0].cf.request; 
   request.headers['my-test-header'] = [{ key: 'my-test-header', value: 'Test Value' }];
   return callback(null,request);
};
```

But any of those headers are not showing. I've been following these documentations too but it seems to be not working.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-cloudfront-headers.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-origin-requests.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-cloudfront-headers.html#cloudfront-headers-viewer-location.

I also saw this question but I couldn't get mine to work
[How do I get CloudFront-Viewer-Country to appear in response headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633610/how-do-i-get-cloudfront-viewer-country-to-appear-in-response-headers)

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: You mention you want to see them in response headers, but also that you added functions to the request triggers... You can see in the question you linked, you should add a function to the response trigger. Also, take a look at response header policy

Comment: No, I want to see them in request headers not response headers @Caldazar